# How to preview source file from treemacs in a project?

Tags: treemacs

I'm using `Doom Emacs` with `treemacs` inside it.

When I look through each source file from side tree, I need to press `Enter` to open the file.

How to view the file content without `Enter` but just move the cursor in the tree menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `P` on the `treemacs` sidebpar.

Once you do that, as and when you move the cursor on the sidebar the displayed file will change.

---

`treemacs-peek-mode` is an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in
`treemacs-peek-mode.el`.

```lisp
(treemacs-peek-mode &optional `ARG`)
```

Minor mode that allows you to peek at buffers before deciding to open them.

**While the mode is active treemacs will automatically display the file at point,
without leaving the treemacs window.**

**Peeking will stop when you leave the treemacs window, be it through a command like `treemacs-RET-action` or some other window selection change.**

**Files` buffers that have been opened for peeking will be cleaned up if they did not exist before peeking started.**

The peeked window can be scrolled using `treemacs-next/previous-line-other-window` and `treemacs-next/previous-page-other-window`

This is a global minor mode.  If called interactively, toggle the `Treemacs-Peek mode` mode.  If the prefix argument is positive, enable the mode, and if it is zero or negative, disable the mode.

If called from Lisp, toggle the mode if `ARG` is `toggle`.  Enable the mode if `ARG` is nil, omitted, or is a positive number.  Disable the mode if `ARG` is a negative number.

To check whether the minor mode is enabled in the current buffer, evaluate `(default-value '`treemacs-peek-mode`)`.

The mode`s hook is called both when the mode is enabled and when it is disabled.

`treemacs-peek-mode` is a variable defined in `treemacs-autoloads.el`.

Its value is nil

Non-nil if Treemacs-Peek mode is enabled.  See the `treemacs-peek-mode` command for a description of this minor mode.  Setting this variable directly does not take effect; either customize it (see the info node `Easy Customization`) or call the function `treemacs-peek-mode`.

You can customize this variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer! It's very clear for the usage.